# Having a PHP function run on jQuery callback

Tags: php, jquery, callback

`$('#target').html(????????)` or `.ajax()` ?

Need this to load a php page in the `<div>` with id target. How do I call that php page?

This is my problem it wasn't my setup it was trying to include the javascript variable obj.info:

```
function(obj){jQuery.ajax({'url':'/controller/\'+obj.info+\'','cache':false,'success':function(html){jQuery('#target').html(html)}})}
```

Whenever I try to work the variable obj.info it the function fails.

Comment: callback? what framework is this?

Comment: You are aware that js is running client-side and php is running server-side...?

Comment: more details + more code = more answers.

Comment: you're gonna need a server request, probably ajax, if you this really had to be from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#target').load('url/to/php/script.php');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks, question I have a js variable I need to pass to the php script, how would I do that?

Comment: You really should read the documentation that I linked to. But you can just pass it into the url: 'url/to/php/script.php?myVar=' + jsVar or you can pass it as a map as the second argument: {myVar:jsVar}

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  'url/to/php/script.php', 
  data: { 'varName': yourJsVariable },
  success: function(response) {
    // your php script returns HTML content
    //
    $('#element').html(response);
  }
});
```

Check the page on .ajax() for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/